# How to check the value of a boolean (set by user) with a variable string?

Tags: string, lua, boolean

The user sets a boolean to true or false.

That does (exemple)

```
ElementNameone = true
ElementNametwo = false
ElementNamethree = true
```

Etc.

Now I have a string that is loaded from a file. The string called name can have values that are Nameone, Nametwo, Namethree, etc. Anyone of them at a time.
Now I would like to be able to do this

```
if Element .. name == true then
do something
```

Except I don't know how to do this properly.

I've tried to do

```
if not not ("Element" .. name) then
```

But it does not work.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if _G["Element" .. name] == true then
    -- do something
end
```

Note that this will work only if the variables set by the user (`ElementNameone`, .. etc.) are globals.

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely you're solving the wrong problem.

You say "the user" sets these variables. How? An end user normally isn't going to be interacting directly with variables inside your program.

Can you use a table instead, with `ElementNameone` as the key and `true` or `false` as the associated value? If so, that would be a lot cleaner.